# Dynaimc class_name in ruby-association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, activesupport-concern

**Problem**
There are some models which should be copied as a template.
For example: There is a News entry and I want to copy it to several groups.
So the copied elements should have the association to the template. And the template should have an association to it's elements.

**Current State**
Because there are several models with the same methods as a copyable element, I've created a concern. I've tried a dynamic association name to link to itself's class but when I create an element, there is a Missmatch Error.

```rb
item = self.class.find_or_create_by(group: group, group_template: self)
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Class(#18118120) expected, got News(#140451780)
```

The association in the concern

```rb
included do
  belongs_to :business_group
  belongs_to :group_template, class_name: self.class.name, foreign_key: :template_id
  has_many :group_elements, class_name: self.class.name, foreign_key: :template_id
end
```

Is there a dynamic solution or should I remove it from the concern and copy it to all models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `included` block `self` is the class being included into. `self.class_name` is probably what you want. `self.class.class_name` is what you have and is asking for the class of a model class, which is `Class`.

The only time you really should use `self.class` is when you are in the scope of an instance of a class and need to access the class of that instance object. In your included block you are already in the class context so `.class` is asking for the class of a class.

Meta-programming can get kind of confusing. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Oh... yes you're right. Now I understand whats going wrong. Thank you very much.